# CMake and Ninja - "missing and no known rule to make it"

Tags: cmake, build-system, ninja

I have this [CMakeLists.txt](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#organization) file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Something.cmake)

add_executable(execute main.cpp)
add_dependencies(somethingInterface Something)
add_dependencies(execute somethingInterface)

include_directories(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
    )
target_compile_options(execute
    PRIVATE
        -std=c++11
        -g
)

add_library(library SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(library PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/library.so)
target_link_libraries(execute
    PRIVATE
        library
)
```

The library shared imported will be created in file *Something.cmake*, but **tt must be built first**.
It was a add_custom_command(TARGET POST_BUILD...) in file *Something.cmake*.

I don't have any problem in using CMake builds here, but when I am using [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html) there an ***error***.

> ninja: error: 'library.so', needed by 'execute', missing and no known rule to make it

Or do you have any suggestion on how can you do this?

I think Ninja has a requirement that "library.so" must exist first, but CMake it is different. It checks whether the library is there at runtime.

Comment: "It was a `add_custom_command(TARGET POST_BUILD...)`" - What is the name of the **target** for this command? (the first argument in the elipsis).

Comment: add_library (somethingInterface empty.cpp)
add_custom_command(TARGET somethingInterface 
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ... #creating the "library" in the CMakeLists.txt
)


It will built only once.

Comment: The name of the target is somethingInterface
which is also the target for the add_library(somethingInterfacer empty.cpp)

Comment: Ok, your previous comment is shown updated only after I re-open the page. That is why I have asked clarification again.

Comment: Are you sure that exactly this `library.so` is created by your custom command? What if you ask ninja for explicitely build the `somethingInterface` target, and then ask ninja to build your `execute`? With correct setup this should work.

Comment: It does create it. Hmmmm
ninja somethingInterface
ninja execute
this work but is there a automatic building it? :) using cmake.

Comment: Yes, it should be built automatically using target-level dependencies. But in ninja you probably need to specify `library.so` as a *BYPRODUCTS* for the command which creates it. See documentation for [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_custom_command.html) about this option.

Comment: What do you mean by *"CMake it's difference"* (seems incomprehensible)? Please respond by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54866067/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is indeed a divergence between the way Make and Ninja handle imported targets. What works with Make, may sometimes not work with Ninja.

In particular, the following lines of code work with Make, but *not* with Ninja:

```
ExternalProject_Add(extProject
    GIT_REPOSITORY <GIT_URL>
    CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS "-
    DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:STRING=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}"
)
add_library(extLib SHARED IMPORTED)
add_dependencies(extLib extProject)
set_target_properties(extLib
    PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/libext.so
)

target_link_libraries(project extLib)
```

The CMake configure step will work fine, but at build time Ninja will complain:

```
ninja: error: '/path/to/libext.so', needed by 'project', missing and no known rule to make it
```

But this will work **fine** with Make.

You need to specify the library as a *byproduct* of the `ExternalProject_Add` comment as [mentioned by Tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54866067/cmake-ninja-missing-and-no-known-rule-to-make-it#comment96512321_54866067), as ExternalProject runs at build time.

The following works fine for me:

```
ExternalProject_Add(extProject
    GIT_REPOSITORY <GIT_URL>
    CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS "-
    DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:STRING=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}"
    BUILD_BYPRODUCTS ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/libext.so
)
add_library(extLib SHARED IMPORTED)
add_dependencies(extLib extProject)
set_target_properties(extLib
    PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/libext.so
)

target_link_libraries(project extLib)
```

Comment: (You don't think CMake is [supported by the syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109). If it was, it would probably be by `lang-cmake`)

Comment: Yes, In my case I added add_library (externalLib SHARED empty.cpp) just to add dependencies to ninja.

Comment: Just want to add that you can use `<INSTALL_DIR>` , `<BINARY_DIR>` (and other substitutions) inside  `ExternalProject_Add`.   For example, if the install step of you external project installs in 'lib/libfoo.a' inside a subdirectory of the build dir, you don't need to know what that subdirectory is, just say `<INSTALL_DIR>/lib/libfoo.a`. These substitution variables are documented in the cmake ExternalProject_Add docs.